# How to handle exit codes with Camel Exec?

Tags: apache-camel

I'm using Camel Exec for automated shutdowns on some of our devices.
The shutdown command is pretty simple, and it mostly works fine:

```
from(START_DEEP_SLEEP)
                .setBody(constant(null)) // we don't want stdin for exec
                .setHeader(ExecBinding.EXEC_COMMAND_ARGS, constant("""shutdown $shutdownDelay "starting deep sleep shutdown" """))
                .to("exec:sudo")
```

Obviously, this command will send a shutdown to the application executing it. That too isn't much of an issue, except that sometimes this produces an exit value of 143. I know the meaning of the return value, and it makes sense to see it here, but this only happens on some devices. Most others just return 0. They are all of the same type, so I really don't know where this discrepancy comes from, but it's not even that big an issue. The shutdown works none the less.

The problem is that camel exec logs this as an error:

```
ERROR 549 --- [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - seda://start-deepsleep] o.a.camel.component.exec.ExecProducer : The command ExecCommand [args=[shutdown, now, starting deep sleep shutdown], executable=sudo, timeout=9223372036854775807, outFile=null, workingDir=null, useStderrOnEmptyStdout=false] returned exit value 143
```

This produces undesired noise in our monitoring, and I would rather not have it logged.

The core issue here is that Camel Exec does *not* throw, so there's no exception I could handle. It just logs the error, which then gets picked up by our log analysis.
I would like to handle that exit code gracefully without camel Exec logging an error. The return value is already logged separately anyways. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

According to the docu http://camel.apache.org/exec.html there is a header ExecBinding.EXEC_EXIT_VALUE filled with the error number. Yours should be 143 (the docu states that this depends on the OS).

That could be a "hook" to handle the log entry, e.g. deleting the last entry with the same error number.
Of course this is only a cosmetic fix. The implementation could be like this:

```
from(START_DEEP_SLEEP)
   .setBody(constant(null)) // we don't want stdin for exec
   .setHeader(ExecBinding.EXEC_COMMAND_ARGS, constant("""shutdown $shutdownDelay "starting deep sleep shutdown" """))
   .to("exec:sudo")
   .when(header(ExecBinding.EXEC_EXIT_VALUE))
   .to("direct:edit_the_log")
```

Please note that I did not test that code. Maybe u access that header with

```
.when(header(EXEC_EXIT_VALUE))
```

instead.

Please, inform me if that could be a proper solution or not.

Comment: Hmmm, the main problem with this is that there's a watcher on the log that sends log entries to a server as they come, so retroactively modifying the log file does not really solve my problem. For now, I just turned logging for the exec component off entirely, that seems to work reasonably well. At least as long as I don't use it for multiple things.

Comment: I believe the problem is not in the camel route. It is the job that writes the entry into the log file that should be reconfigured.